# A Python Module Command Output Request (on Linux)

Tags: python, module, output

I need to know how following Python `psutil` module commands outputs are for a multiple CPU (CPU sockets) computer:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0.3, percpu=True))
print(psutil.sensors_temperatures(fahrenheit=False))
print(psutil.sensors_fans())
```

**Note:** Python package `psutil` should be installed.
**Note2:** Last two commands are not available on Windows. They should be run on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`psutil documentaion`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest)

- [`cpu_percent`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_percent) : 1-or more CPU returns same : 1-d list of `cpu_percent` value

  - `percpu=False` returns `int` such as `2.3`
  - `percpu=True` returns `list[int]` such as

    - for 1CPU-4cores-8threads `[23.8, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 23.8]`
    - for 4CPU-4x4cores-4x8threads `[23.8, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 23.8,23.8, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 23.8,23.8, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 23.8,23.8, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 23.8]`
- [`sensor_temparatures`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.sensors_temperatures) returns `dict[str,list[namedtuple]` such as

  ```
  {'acpitz'  : [shwtemp(label='', current=47.0, high=103.0, critical=103.0)],
   'asus'    : [shwtemp(label='', current=47.0, high=None, critical=None)],
   'coretemp': [shwtemp(label='Physical id 0', current=52.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
               shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=45.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
               shwtemp(label='Core 1', current=52.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
               shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=45.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0),
               shwtemp(label='Core 3', current=47.0, high=100.0, critical=100.0)]}
  ```
- [`sensors_fans`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.sensors_fans)  returns `dict[str,list[namedtuple]` such as

  ```
  {'asus': [sfan(label='cpu_fan', current=3200)]}
  ```